# Which proof method to use for the following binomial coefficient theorem?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

In the given exercise, I should prove that $\binom{m+n} r = \sum_{k=0}^r \binom{m} k\cdot \binom{n}{r-k}$.

I have tried rewriting it in fractions, as well as using induction for the sum, however I haven't gotten any result due to being stuck at some point.

I'm fairly new to this website so excuse me my missing formatting skills, I have uploaded an image for you down below.

I don't want a full proof in the replies for that but if one of you could advise me which method to use and some tips on this proof I would really appreciate it.

Thank you!

[exercise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEzhR.png)

Comment: Ssarch up Van der Monde’s identity.

Comment: @insipidintegrator thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The assertion can be proven with virtually no Math.

$\displaystyle \binom{m+n}{r}~$ represents the number of ways of choosing $r$ elements, sampling without replacement, from $(m+n)$ elements.

The set of such *ways* can be partitioned into $(r+1)$ mutually exclusive subsets, depending on how many of the $(r)$ items come from the first $m$ items.  Clearly, the number of such items must be some element $~k \in \{0,1,2,\cdots,r\}.$

For each such element $k$, the number of ways of choosing $k$ elements from the first $m$ items, and then choosing $(r-k)$ elements from the remaining $n$ items is

$$\binom{m}{k} \times \binom{n}{r- k}.$$

So, the assertion is proven using nothing more than intuition around Set theory.  No other Math needed.

Answer (score 0):

$(1 + p)^{m+n} = (1 + p)^{m} . (1 + p)^{n}$

Then compare the coefficient of these Binomial Expansion on both sides for $p^r$